# How do I tell when the top or bottom of an element scrolls to the top of the page using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a web page with two 100% height divs like this...

```
<style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #wrapper{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .scroll-item{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
</style>
...
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="test1"
             class="scroll-item">Simple Test 1</div>
        <div id="test2"
             class="scroll-item">Simple Test 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now I want to "select" the one that is currently scrolled to. This means that the top of the element has reached the top of the browser but the bottom has not. This is where I am getting confused here is the JS...

```
<script type="module">
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        const handleScroll = function(info){
            const items = body.getElementsByClassName("scroll-item");
            for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
                const item = items[i];
                // TODO How do I tell if it is there
            }
        }
        body.addEventListener("wheel",handleScroll);
</script>
```

I have tried using the bounding box but I cannot figure out how to get that to work correctly.

How do I tell when the top or bottom of the element reaches the top of the browser (given possible offset for navbar)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).
It gives you the [DOMRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect) object containing the size and coordinates of an element.

```js
...
if (item.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
  // items top has reached beyond window top
}
if (item.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > window.innerHeight) {
  // items bottom is beyond window bottom
}
...
```

For advanced usage, see [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver), which detects an elements visibility inside the viewport.

Comment: This works good as well as long as there is no header. But I have a header I will open another question since it expands the topic a bit but see below for an example of what I mean. And thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the wrapper to get current position and listen scroll event, also, is better to listen *scroll* instead of *wheel* event.

```js
        // Use the wrapper to get and listen scroll
        const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper')
        const handleScroll = function(event) {
            const top = wrapper.scrollTop;
            document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-item').forEach((item, index) => {
                // Calculate item bottom position
                const bottom = item.offsetTop + item.offsetHeight;
                // Is the scroll between item top and bottom?
                if(top >= item.offsetTop && top < bottom) {
                    console.log(`Item ${index} is active`);
                }
            });
        }
        // scroll event is more accurate than wheel
        wrapper.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```

```css
html, body{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #wrapper{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .scroll-item{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="test1"
             class="scroll-item">Simple Test 1</div>
        <div id="test2"
             class="scroll-item">Simple Test 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked with my simplified example. In the real world my wrapper is height: calc(100% - 64px); and there us a 64px header. When I try to do this like that item.offsetHeight is always 0. Any idea why this might be? This newer example is available https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-demo/blob/SCROLL_WORK/modules/esm/jrg-site/index.html

Comment: So it works with https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-demo/blob/SCROLL_WORK/modules/esm/jrg-site/test1.html but not https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-demo/blob/SCROLL_WORK/modules/esm/jrg-site/test.html I will open a second question

Comment: Also scroll does not work for macbook finger scrolling AFAIK